# how to quickly expand a dataframe using the lists inside the dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains one column with a unique string identifier, another column with a simple string/keyword, and a third column that is a string separated by commas ("categories").  This dataframe has x rows and the categories string in the 3rd column may have any number of commas.  I want to split the categories by commas, append the keyword string to each of those separated categories, then create a new dataframe that consists of a column for the unique string identifier and a column for each new string that was created.

Here's an example of my starting DF:

```
startDF <- data.frame(uq_id = c("44ffd", "t3dd", "rrk33--ds", "limmt3"),
                      keyword = c("citizen", "river", "mouse", "hello"),
                      categories = c("App, Restaurant, Hotel", "Field, Place", "Movie", "App, Hotel, Theater, Show"))
```

And here's what I'd like the final DF to look like:

```
endDF <- data.frame(uq_iq = c("44ffd", "44ffd", "44ffd", "t3dd", "t3dd", "rrk33--ds", "limmt3", "limmt3", "limmt3", "limmt3"),
                    combo = c("citizen App", "citizen Restaurant", "citizen Hotel", "river Field", "river Place", "mouse Movie",
                              "hello App", "hello Hotel", "hello Theater", "hello Show"))
```

Currently, I'm looping through each element of the DF and creating this new dataframe row by row, but that is slow and I feel like there must be a better way using apply, strsplit, paste, etc.
Is there a quick and simple solution for this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`, `separate_rows` we can first separate each `category` into individual row and then `unite` them with `keyword` column.

```
library(tidyverse)

startDF %>%
  separate_rows(categories) %>%
  unite(combo, keyword, categories, sep = " ")

#       uq_id              combo
#1      44ffd        citizen App
#2      44ffd citizen Restaurant
#3      44ffd      citizen Hotel
#4       t3dd        river Field
#5       t3dd        river Place
#6  rrk33--ds        mouse Movie
#7     limmt3          hello App
#8     limmt3        hello Hotel
#9     limmt3      hello Theater
#10    limmt3         hello Show
```

---

Base R method could be by splitting the `categories` on comma, repeating `uq_id` based on the `length` of each `category` and create a new dataframe by pasting the string together with `keyword` using `mapply`.

```
list_cat <- strsplit(startDF$categories, ",")
data.frame(uq_id = rep(startDF$uq_id, lengths(list_cat)), 
           combo = unlist(mapply(paste, list_cat, startDF$keyword)))
```

Read `startDF` using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to keep them as characters instead of factors.

Answer (score 0):

A different `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
startDF %>%
 mutate(categories = strsplit(as.character(categories), ", ", fixed = TRUE)) %>%
 unnest() %>%
 transmute(uq_id = uq_id,
           combo = paste(keyword, categories, sep = " "))

       uq_id              combo
1      44ffd        citizen App
2      44ffd citizen Restaurant
3      44ffd      citizen Hotel
4       t3dd        river Field
5       t3dd        river Place
6  rrk33--ds        mouse Movie
7     limmt3          hello App
8     limmt3        hello Hotel
9     limmt3      hello Theater
10    limmt3         hello Show
```